# Strip under the tab is not drawn

Tags: android, tabs, strip

In my **activity** I'm doing this to setup the TabHost:

```
//...     
        mTabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().setDividerDrawable(R.drawable.my_divider_tab);
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(true);
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().setLeftStripDrawable(R.drawable.my_strip_tab);
        mTabHost.getTabWidget().setRightStripDrawable(R.drawable.my_strip_tab);
        setupTab(new TextView(this), getString(R.string.device_text_tab));
        setupTab(new TextView(this), getString(R.string.sensor_text_tab));
        setupTab(new TextView(this), getString(R.string.actuator_text_tab));
//...

private void setupTab(final View view, final String tag) {
    
    View tabview = createTabView(mTabHost.getContext(), tag);
        TabSpec setContent = mTabHost.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(new TabContentFactory() {
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {return view;}
    });
    mTabHost.addTab(setContent);
}

private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) {
    
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.state_tabwidget, null);
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
    tv.setText(text);
    return view;
}
```

**my_strip_tab.xml** is just a rectangle shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    
    <solid 
        android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    
    <size 
        android:width="0dp"
        android:height="2dp"/>
</shape>
```

The vertical divider is drawn. But the strip under the tabs isn't shown...

What could be the problem? The size of `my_strip_tab`?

I just found that:

```
/**
 * Controls whether the bottom strips on the tab indicators are drawn or
 * not.  The default is to draw them.  If the user specifies a custom
 * view for the tab indicators, then the TabHost class calls this method
 * to disable drawing of the bottom strips.
 * @param stripEnabled true if the bottom strips should be drawn.
 */
```

Here: [TabWidgetExample](http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/widget/TabWidget.java.shtml)

So it seems like when we use custom view for the tabs (like I am doing), the strip is automatically disabled...
How can I enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution that I found to solve this issue was:

```
//...
<TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


        <View
            android:id="@+id/my_strip_tab"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp" 
            android:background="@drawable/my_strip_tab"/>

//...

    </FrameLayout>
```

**my_strip_tab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape  
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid 
        android:color="#67E667"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: I was having the same issue.  I solved it by 1) moving my setStrip lines below setting up my tab stuff and 2) my drawable was not specifying size. Works good now, thanks to amp and @brian wang

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you have to do is move this block of codes

```
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setStripEnabled(true);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setLeftStripDrawable(R.drawable.my_strip_tab);
    mTabHost.getTabWidget().setRightStripDrawable(R.drawable.my_strip_tab);
```

after all your setupTab()

The reason, if you look into the Google documentation, is when you use custom views for the tab indicators, the setStripEnabled(false) will be called automatically. You just need to re-enable it again after you setup all the custom views or the tab indicators.